# post-install hook issue, and segmentation fault 11 occured

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am using **pod 1.1.1** and facing issues with it.

- Xcode 7.3.1 with Mac: Sierra

Facing issue on post-install hook and if that is removed i get Segmentaton Fault 11.

> > [!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.
>
> undefined method `project' for #

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == 'Pods-T-Appboy-iOS-SDK'
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
                config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << 'ABK_ENABLE_IDFA_COLLECTION=1'
            end
        end
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

The Hooks-API has changed quite a wile ago.

In your `Podfile`, replace `project` with `pods_project` and run `pod install`afterwards.

Find detailed information [here](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.38/).

Comment: Got a segmentation fault 11, pod installed.

Comment: Please post all relevant available information. Podfile and such.

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing via CocoaPods you should be able to remove the 'Pods-T-' part when going through in a loop like https://github.com/Appboy/appboy-ios-sdk/blob/f5155ff317f9304c6984c7b2e0b17d90cc277e4a/HelloSwift/Podfile#L12